# $(1+x+x^2)^n = \sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_{r}\cdot x^{r}$ and $\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\cdot a_{r}\cdot \binom{n}{r} = k\cdot \binom{n}{\frac{n}{3}}$. Then $k=$

Tags: combinatorics

If $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $\displaystyle (1+x+x^2)^n = \sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_{r}\cdot x^{r}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\cdot a_{r}\cdot \binom{n}{r} = k\cdot \binom{n}{\frac{n}{3}}$. Then $k=$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$$\displaystyle(1+x+x^2)^n = a_{0}x^0+a_{1}x^{1}+a_{2}x^2+.......+a_{r}x^{r}.....+a_{2n}x^{2n}$

Now Replace $\displaystyle x\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$

$\displaystyle (1+x+x^2)^{n} = x^{2n}\left(a_{0}x^0+a_{1}x^{1}+a_{2}x^2+......+a_{r}x^{r}......+a_{2n}x^{2n}\right)$

Now Did not Understand How can I calculate it

Help Required

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace $x\rightarrow -x$, we have 
$$
(1-x+x^2)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{2n} (-1)^r a_r x^r. $$

Then 
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\cdot a_{r}\cdot \binom{n}{r}$$
represents the coefficient of $x^n$ in the following 
$$
(1-x+x^2)^n (1+x)^n= (1+x^3)^n$$

Comment: Thanks i707107 would you like to explain me in  Detail,